# Is there a way to create interactive plots (a la D3) in IPython notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I found those two answers:
[Animated graphs in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611705/animated-graphs-in-ipython-notebook) ,
[How to grab matplotlib plot as html in ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580684/how-to-grab-matplotlib-plot-as-html-in-ipython-notebook)

But they don't address interactivity. I would like to display a plot with 2-3 curves and let the user hover those curves to receive more details or control the parameters that are used to generate those curves from a combo-box

Answer (score 9):

check the following answer at [iPython: Manipulate-like command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21891699/1204331).

as well as the two following directions:

1. IPython `interact/ive` as motivated in [IPython - The Attributes ofSoftware and How They Affect Our Work - Brian Granger](http://vimeo.com/79832657) near 32m:12s; and available at [IPython's github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython)
2. [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/index.html) provides a powerful and succinct syntax, based on vega-lite; see the [gallery](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/index.html#example-gallery)
3. [MPLD3: Bringing Matplotlib to the Browser](http://mpld3.github.io/index.html)

Comment: +1 mpld3 is pretty sweet. You can just import it, and run `mpld3.enable_notebook()` below your `%pylab inline` call, and all plots become interactive. Can get a bit slow though.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe the standard matplotlib plots are capable of the interactivity you want.  [Chaco](http://code.enthought.com/chaco/) can do interactive graphs, but not in an ipython notebook, AFAICT.  Your best bet is probably [Bokeh](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/Bokeh).  It outputs to Javascript/HTML, can do interactive graphs, and has an example of using it from ipython.

Comment: unfortunately bokeh is going with a canvas implementation as opposed to svg, so interactivity will be severely hampered. plotly is based on d3js, allowing much richer (imo) experience

Answer (score 7):

You may want to check out [Plotly](https://plot.ly). They render interactive D3 plots inside IPython Notebooks (examples [here](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/). You can export as static images as well, and zoom, hover, pan, and see text on the hover. Interactivity is one of the pitches they're emphasizing. For more, you can also use [IPython widgets](http://moderndata.plot.ly/widgets-in-ipython-notebook-and-plotly/) inside the Notebook, which gives you more control and options. For example:

[image]

Comment: +1 for a pointer in the right direction. If you want interactive, streaming plots embedded in an IPython notebook, (as did I) plotly is probably a better choice than bokeh (I could only get streaming scatter plots to work in bokeh, not histograms box & whisker, etc.).

Comment: Is there a free version of Plotly? (one which does not require the user to keep their plots public, that is)

Comment: @eldad-a  seems like you can plot privately, I plotted a few, see https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/

Answer (score 3):

Like @AFoglia, I'm going to suggest other libraries that might be what you're looking for: [Tangle](https://github.com/worrydream/Tangle), [Mathematica Notebooks](http://www.wolfram.com/products/player/), [IPython / Bokeh](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/Bokeh), [RactiveJS](http://www.ractivejs.org/), or [ReactJS](http://facebook.github.io/react/).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be the [Charts](https://github.com/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts) library. It enables you to use the excellent [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) javascript library to make beautiful and interactive plots out of the box.

Some features:

- Vector plots which you can download in .png, .jpg and .svg formats so you will never run into resolution problems.
- Interactive charts (zoom, slide, hover over points, ...)
- Usable in an IPython notebook
- Explore hundreds of data structures at the same time using the asynchronous plotting capabilities.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the library*

Answer (score 1):

You can run javascript straight from IPython notebooks (`%%html` and `%%javascript`), so it should be possible to run **D3** code. Check this [video](http://youtu.be/8UtoIR2IEkI). The exact way in which this would be implemented is not set in stone yet, as this is a feature for IPython 2.0. There are many hacks available as of now, as well as projects that try to port some characteristics of D3 to Python (such as [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) and [python-nvd3](https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3)).

I have not yet tested any of these. My own bias would be to try the example below first, which is static, but uses D3 directly (so it should *theoretically* work for interactive plots):

- [gist](https://gist.github.com/z-m-k/4484816)
- [notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4484816/ipyD3sample.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

Other answeres here seem to be outdated. **IPython 2.0 has support** for interactive widgets. [Read the docs including some examples](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Index.ipynb), but note that the nbviewer.ipython.org does not show the interactive widgets. Copy & pasting the examples to [try.jupyter.org](http://try.jupyter.org) works.