# iPython: Manipulate-like command

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, ipython, jupyter-notebook, sage

In Wolfram Mathematica, I can interactively modify the value of a parameter by using the `Manipulate[]` command.

[For example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html), `Manipulate[n, {n, 1, 20}]`
shows a slider through which is possible to vary the value of `n`.

Is there any simple way (i.e. something like a magic or a decorator, [like in SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/prep/Quickstarts/Interact.html)) to achieve the same result in the IPython notebook?

Comment: i don't know, but sage == ipython under the hood, so probably you could adapt that code fairly easily.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update**
This was added in IPython 2.0 (released Apr 1, 2014), it's called [Interactive Widgets](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Index.ipynb) and works in web notebooks.

**Original answer**
This is ongoing work for 2.0 (release December something-ish) Have a look at the IPython-dev meeting on YouTube to see progress. The [last meeting from oct 21 at 28min-ish](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsYqkokRgKk&feature=share&t=28m14s) has a widget demo by John then `interact` by Brian.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure whether this would satisfy all your needs as it is still experimental, but seems to do what you asked for - look at [static interactive widgets](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/) by Jake VanderPlas.

What I did to get running was the following:

Get the source and install:

```
git clone https://github.com/jakevdp/ipywidgets
pip install ./ipywidgets
```

start an ipython notebook and experiment with the notebook `example.ipynb` in the `ipywidgets` directory

There's another type of interactive visualisation, where panning, zoom and meta-data are available (possibly more). It is by the same author and reported in his blog [D3 Plugins: Truly Interactive Matplotlib In Your Browser](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/01/10/d3-plugins-truly-interactive/).

There are also nice docs: [MPLD3: Bringing Matplotlib to the Browser](http://mpld3.github.io/index.html)

To experiment with it I did more or less the same:

```
git clone https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3
pip install ./mpld3/
```

One can now run  the `create_example.py` script, or even better, start an `ipython notebook` and play with the provided `mpld3/notebooks/mpld3_demo.ipynb` as well as with the attractive examples of `mpld3_plugins` posted in the blog.

It may be worth noting that I am using the Anaconda distro of python, which includes Jinja2; as far as I know Jinja2 is a requirement for mpld3.

I do agree that an `@interact` decorator a la sage would be nice.