# Animating plots on ipython 2 for mac os

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to animate (at run time) [unlike this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611705/animated-graphs-in-ipython-notebook) in mac os and ipython notebook 2.0.  I have the following code:

```
%pylab inline
import time, sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
f, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0,6,200)

for i in range(10):
  y = i/10*np.sin(x) 
  print i
  ax.plot(x,y)
  time.sleep(0.1)
  clear_output(True)
  display(f)
  ax.cla() # turn this off if you'd like to "build up" plots
plt.close()
```

Which seems to almost work, as the `print` is working without flashing (a previous problem, corrected by `clear_output`), but the axes are not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `i` is an integer, so the line `y = i/10*np.sin(x)` does integer division, which always returns 0. It is animating! But the result is always a flat line at 0. Change that line to

```
y = float(i)/10*np.sin(x)
```

When you do that, you'll notice that it doesn't animate in a very nice way. To make it look better, we can explicitly set the y-axis limits instead of letting Matplotlib do it automatically. Inside your loop, add the line

```
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
```

The final code below animates nicely.

```
%pylab inline
import time, sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
f, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0,6,200)

for i in range(10):
  y = float(i)/10*np.sin(x) 
  print i
  ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
  ax.plot(x,y)
  time.sleep(0.1)
  clear_output(True)
  display(f)
  ax.cla() # turn this off if you'd like to "build up" plots
plt.close()
```